# How to receive only the name of a month as input parameter and not entire date in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DISPLAY_PRESC(
P_PATIENT_ID IN NUMBER,
P_MONTH IN DATE)

IS

V_patient_name PATIENT.PATIENT_NAME%TYPE;

CURSOR PRES_CURSOR IS
SELECT PRESCRIPTION_ID, PRESCRIPTION_DATE
FROM PATIENT PAT, PRESCRIPTION PRES
WHERE PAT.PATIENT_ID = P_PATIENT_ID
AND PAT.PATIENT_ID = PRES.PATIENT_ID
AND PRES.PRESCRIPTION_DATE = P_MONTH;

BEGIN

SELECT PATIENT_NAME INTO V_PATIENT_NAME
FROM PATIENT
WHERE PATIENT_ID = P_PATIENT_ID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('List of prescriptions for: ' || V_PATIENT_NAME|| ' during: ' ||P_MONTH);

FOR PRES_REC IN PRES_CURSOR LOOP

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (PRES_REC.PRESCRIPTION_ID|| ' ' || PRES_REC.PRESCRIPTION_DATE);

END LOOP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('*** END OF REPORT ***');

END DISPLAY_PRESC;
```

This procedure is supposed to display all the prescriptions of a particular patient for a certain month.

**input parameters**
eg: Patient_ID = 10; 
P_Month = 'June' & not '01-Jun-07' like I currently have to enter it.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Use to_char(p_month,'Month') in dbms_output instead of p_month

Comment: If this routine gets an input of 'June', how do you know which year goes with this month? Or do you want all prescriptions written during June of any year?

Comment: Yes I would like too see all of the prescriptions during June of any year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code to display prescriptions in certain month in all years:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DISPLAY_PRESC(P_PATIENT_ID IN NUMBER,
                                          P_MONTH  IN varchar2)

 IS

  V_patient_name PATIENT.PATIENT_NAME%TYPE;

  CURSOR PRES_CURSOR IS
    SELECT PRESCRIPTION_ID, PRESCRIPTION_DATE
      FROM PATIENT PAT, PRESCRIPTION PRES
     WHERE PAT.PATIENT_ID = P_PATIENT_ID
       AND PAT.PATIENT_ID = PRES.PATIENT_ID
       ------ modified
       AND trim(Initcap(to_char(PRES.PRESCRIPTION_DATE, 'month')) ) = trim(Initcap(P_MONTH))
       ------ added
       order by PRES.PRESCRIPTION_DATE ;

BEGIN

  SELECT PATIENT_NAME
    INTO V_PATIENT_NAME
    FROM PATIENT
   WHERE PATIENT_ID = P_PATIENT_ID;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('List of prescriptions for: ' || V_PATIENT_NAME ||
                       ' during: ' || Initcap(P_MONTH) );

  FOR PRES_REC IN PRES_CURSOR LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PRES_REC.PRESCRIPTION_ID || ' ' ||
                         PRES_REC.PRESCRIPTION_DATE);

  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*** END OF REPORT ***');

END DISPLAY_PRESC;
```

I suggest you to keep `p_month` as `date` parameter and handle it in your program interface code before sending it as parameter for `DISPLAY_PRESC` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Date object is a full date which includes year,month, day, hour, minutes, seconds.

If you want to get only a month you should get either a VARCHAR2, or a number, and migrate it to the required date.

There's no "month" data type in Oracle, so if you want to handle only monthes you'll have to do it manually in your code.

The way most of the systems do the same thing is getting to full dates, which they extract data between these dates (with days, and year), and that way bypass the problem you face right now.
Also remember that each year there is June, so you would probably need the year as input - so send in 06/01/2014 00:00:00 is actually helpful a bit - since you get one object, which you can extract two pieces of data from.